# What happens with partially empty magazines after a mission in Phoenix Point?

Tags: phoenix-point

Phoenix Point tends to track ammo usage closely. Similar to the X-COM games and Xenonauts, you get fine-grained control of how much ammo to equip soldiers with (in terms of spare magazines) and reloading early will waste the remainder of the ammo in the magazine. Thus encouraging more planning for when to reload - do it early and you waste ammo. Do it late and you might not have ammo for an important firefight.

However, I cannot seem to figure out exactly how it tracks the ammo after a mission.

Here is an example scenario: I equip a soldier with Deimos AR-L which has ammo capacity of 60. During the mission I use 12 of the ammo and the assault rifle is left with 48 ammo.

What I have noticed is that if I have no other magazines, then the weapon is left with 48 ammo for the next mission. This seems OK for me. What I cannot seem to understand what happens if I do have an extra magazine.

Does the game then "reload" the assault rifle thus wasting the 48 ammo and using up an entire magazine for it? Or are the 48 remaining ammo tracked somewhere?